Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'IdentityServer
Getting error on running Run that says:
Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'IdentityServer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
Identity Server is MVC project which i'm trying to run.
The problem occurs only on my AppleSilicon working machine in Rider. On Windows it is working without any issue.
Any ideas?
Tried cleaning and rebuilding solution. Deleting whole solution and cloning it back. Deleting bin and obj. Running with external console and in terminal. Result is the same

This article might help: is-it-possible-to-develop-asp-net-mvc-applications-in-visual-studio-for-mac

@RyanWilson project is .net 8. So it should be able to start. And btw I have WebAPI in the same solution that starts and works correctly
